# UITableViewCell font size is not changing

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts, uitableview, uifont

I'm trying to get the font size on my UITableViewCell to be smaller. Here is the code I have:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

    UILabel *nameLabel; 
    UISwitch *mySwitch;
    if ( cell == nil ) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        nameLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 220, 13, 100, 20 )] autorelease];
        nameLabel.tag = 22;
        nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 5.0];
        nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        nameLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: nameLabel];

        mySwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        mySwitch.tag = ((400*(indexPath.section+1))+indexPath.row);
        [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell addSubview:mySwitch];
        cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;


    }
    else {
        nameLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: 22];
        mySwitch = (UISwitch *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:((400*(indexPath.section+1))+indexPath.row)];
    }

    nameLabel.textLabel.text = @"Hello";


}
```

But the font of the label is certainly not coming out to be size 5. It's normal font and normal size, probably about font size 12, or whatever the default is. Why can't I change the font size?

Comment: is there a reason you're adding the nameLabel to the cell's contentView twice?

Comment: typo, sorry. I've removed one of them. It still has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Instead of  `nameLabel.textLabel.text = @"Hello";`

Use

```
nameLabel.text = @"Hello";
```

Answer (score 2):

Unrelated to your issue, but there's no need to add the switch as a subview. Setting the accessory view should add it to the cell and retain it.

```
    [cell addSubview:mySwitch];
    cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;
```

...should just be...

```
    [cell setAccessoryView:mySwitch];
```